# Queries with OR operator on JSONB column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I have a JSONB column named `metadata` on a `users` table. I want to get users where `metadata->a->b` is 5, 6, or 7. I can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE metadata @> '{"a": {"b": 5}}' 
   OR metadata @> '{"a": {"b": 6}}' 
   OR metadata @> '{"a": {"b": 7}}'; --etc.
```

Is there a more efficient way to do a query like this? Something like a `IN` for JSONB?

Comment: `(metadata->'a'->'b')::int in (5,6,7)` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... WHERE metadata->'a'->>'b' IN (5, 6, 7)
```

You can create a B-tree index on the expression that *might* help:

```
CREATE INDEX ON users ((metadata->'a'->>'b'));
```

Comment: Ok thanks. About your side note, what kind of index should I create? GIN index is for the whole JSONB column, I just have to create a "classic" index?

Comment: I have extended the answer to cover that.